# Need transit Visa for dubai for Indian Passport holders Or no

Tags: visas, transit

Sir i am leaving from Ecuador to india on 19th august,16, on KLM flight,from dubai to Amritsar i going by Spice jet,i need to Stay at dubai International airport for 5 hours,either i need the transit Visa Or no ? Kindly reply and make me oblige
                                   Amrit Sidhu

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a transit visa, as both airlines are using Terminal 1. Have a safe flight.